# Django password reset _getfullpathname error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I am trying to set up a password reset form but I get the following error after trying to send an email, weirdly I noticed that if I put email that doesn't match any of the emails provided by users it works, error only occurs when email matches one provided by a user.
Error:

```
TypeError at /password_reset/
_getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views #import this

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_confirm.html"), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path("password_reset/", views.password_reset_request, name="password_reset"),
]
```

views.py

```
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data))
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    email_template_name = "registration/password_reset_email.txt"
                    c = {
                    "email":user.email,
                    'domain':'127.0.0.1:8000',
                    'site_name': 'Website',
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    "user": user,
                    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                    'protocol': 'http',
                    }
                    email = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                    try:
                        send_mail(subject, email, 'admin@example.com' , [user.email], fail_silently=False)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    return redirect ("/password_reset/done/")
    password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="registration/password_reset_form.html", context={"password_reset_form":password_reset_form})
```

password_reset_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

            

    <!--Reset Password-->
    <div class="container p-5">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold mt-3">Reset Password</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Forgotten your password? Enter your email address below, and we'll email instructions for setting a new one.</p>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ password_reset_form }}                    
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send email</button>
        </form>
    </div> 

{% endblock %}
```

I have added `'django.contrib.auth'` to my INSTALLED_APPS and `EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend"` line in  settings.py

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you are passing a type of `NONE` somewhere. Can you add your `settings.py`?

Comment: And also from what you mentioned here `I noticed that if I put email that doesn't match any of the emails provided by users it works, error only occurs when email matches one provided by a user. Error:`. So that means if a user doesnt exist, this  `associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data))` yields true?